# Unexpected output when querying for word index in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, python-re

So i am feeding a dataframe, one row at a time, into a function to search for the first occurrence of a word and return its index into a new dataframe column.

```
def fix_df(row):
    words= row['t_sents']
    tags= row['t_tags']
    return find_start(words, tags)    #get a row slice from two columns, 

def find_start(words, tags):
    try:
        idx = tags.index('ante')
    except ValueError:
        idx = None
    return idx 

bant_df['start_ante'] = bant_df.apply(fix_df, axis=1) #calling the ff
```

My output however, is unexpected. for example looking at the dataframe snapeshot

```
    t_sents     t_tags  start_ante
0   'Sandwich', 'in', 'Kent', ';', 'until', '2011...    '0', '0', '0', '0', 'ante', 'ante', '0', '0',...    22.0
1   'If', 'the', 'deals', 'were', 'properly', 'ac...    'ante', 'ante', 'ante', 'ante', 'ante', 'ante...    2.0
2   'These', 'distortions', 'have', 'seen', 'one'...    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ...    152.0
```

my expected answer in the first frame ought to be 4, yet i have 22. The second row ought to be 0, yet I have 2. what could be wrong?  Note that i only queried for the word in the second column t_tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `find_start` function `idx = tags.index('ante')` `tags` is a `pandas.Series` not a `list` so the `index` method works differently. If you get the data from `tags` by doing `tags.values.tolist()` you can then use the `list` index method which should get you the right result.

I made an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tags'] = ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'ante', 'ante', '0', '0']

type(df['tags'])
>>> pandas.core.series.Series

# you can get a list as
type(df['tags'].values.tolist()) # .values gets a numpy array which has a .tolist method
>>> list

df['tags'].values.tolist().index('ante')
>>> 4
```

Comment: Somehow, This does not work for me. it works when i create a sample dataframe, but with my own particular dataframe, it doesnt work. i am beginning to think that the problem may lie there

Comment: like i said, there is nothing wrong with your answer, and there are so many good answers on stackoverflow, even to the point of overkill, but i cannot understand where those strange index numbers are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
import ast
```

then slightly modifying my initial code

```
def fix_df(row):
    words= row['t_sents']
    tags= row['t_tags']
    tags_as_list = ast.literal_eval(tags)    #included line of code
    return find_start(words, tags_as_list) 

def find_start(words, tags):
    try:
        idx = tags.index('ant')
    except ValueError:
        idx = None
    return idx 

df['start_ante'] = df.apply(fix_df, axis=1)
```

This gets it working normally